# What is the shortest notation to define an operator as a method alias in Scala?

Tags: scala, methods, operators, alias

Given the generic `register` method below I would like to define the `:=` operator as a symbolic alias.

```
def register[Prop <: Property[_]](prop: Prop): Prop

@inline
final def :=[Prop <: Property[_]] = register[Prop] _
```

Originally I wanted to write something like this:

```
val := = register _
```

But that gives me the function signature `Nothing => Nothing`. My next attempt was to parameterize it with the type `Prop` but that apparently works only if I make it a `def`, which can take type parameters and pass them onwards.

Ideally I would like to omit the `@inline` annotation but I am not sure what object code the Scala compiler makes out of it.

**Most important** my goal is it not to have the `:=` method duplicate all parts of the `register` method's signature except for the name and then simply let the former delegate to the latter.

Answer (score 2):

```
def :=[Prop <: Property[_]](prop: Prop) = register(prop)
```

should work.

Comment: Method delegation with duplicated signatures is exactly what I wanted to avoid. See my last paragraph "Most important ...". Also I don't want to have to manually forward any arguments.

Comment: @TimFriske Unfortunately, you'll have to, if you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there's any way to achieve what you're after (basically what `alias` gives you in Ruby) in Scala as it currently stands. The [autoproxy plugin](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=275135) is an attempt to address this kind of problem, but it's not really ready for production use yet due to various issues with generating code in compiler plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
def := : Prop => Prop = register
```

So basically here you define a function of type (Prop => Prop) that just references another function.